# does anyone know how this text is encrypted?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ciphers

Im trying to solve a copher challange, but i have no idea on this question. does anyone have any ideas on the encryption method used here?

---

Dvoo wlmv, blf'ev hloevw xrksvi xszoovmtv mfnyvi gdl. Gsrh gbkv lu xrksvi rh z hkvxrzo hfyhgrgfgrlm xrksvi pmldm zh Zgyzhs, zmw rh nzwv yb ivevihrmt gsv zokszyvg zmw ivkozxrmt gsv ozhg ovggvi drgs gsv urihg, gsv kvmfogrnzgv ovggvi drgs gsv hvxlmw, zmw hl lm. Rg rh xzoovw Zgyzhs yvxzfhv rg dzh lirtrmzoob wlmv drgs gsv Svyivd zokszyvg, zmw rg gllp rgh mznv uiln gsv urihg zmw ozhg, zmw hvxlmw zmw kvmfogrnzgv ovggvih rm gszg zokszyvg.

Hfyhgrgfgrlm xrksvih ivkozxv gsv ovggvih lu gsv nvhhztv drgs lgsvi ovggvih. Xzvhzi hsrug zmw Zgyzhs ziv uzriob hrnkov hfyhgrgfgrlm xrksvih gl xizxp, yvxzfhv lmxv blf'ev nzwv z uvd tfvhhvh rg'h vzhb gl hklg gsv hbhgvn gszg szh yvvm fhvw gl wvxrwv lm gsv hfyhgrgfgrlmh. Gsv mvcg nvhhztv dlm'g yv jfrgv hl vzhb gl xizxp, hl ivnvnyvi gl ollp uli kfmxgfzgrlm, hrmtov ovggvih zmw hslig dliwh.

Urmzoob, gsv pvbdliw gl zxxvhh gsv gsriw xszoovmtv rh gvzxzpv.

Comment: If you need help with a challenge, please let us know the methods you tried and what conclusions you have drawn from applying them. You might also want to read about common methods to crack substitution ciphers.

Comment: hint: if in english, which it seems to be, there's not many two-letter words, and several are repeated in the ciphertext. it's a simple substitution, there's not very many combinations. try them all and spell check the results, sorting all results by fewest errors.

Comment: looking at it, no math or paper, it seems that a=z, b=y, m=n, etc.

Comment: heh, i was right, a-z|z-a... here's a teaser: `well done, you've solved cipher challenge number two ....
finally, the keyword to access the third challenge is teacake.`

Comment: Would you mind sharing where the puzzle comes from so that others can proceed to the 3rd challenge?

Comment: It was the Nrich maths cipher challange.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how this text is encrypted?

Yes, but I do not.

Joking aside, it appears to be a substitution cipher of some sort. It's not a rot-13 "Caesar" cipher.

My recommendation would be to try some basic code-breaking methods. If only a single key was used, you could try doing a frequency analysis of the letters in the ciphertext and correlate them to [english letter frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language). Additionally, you could take the top most [common words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English#100_most_common_words) used in the english language and try seeing where they may fit in the ciphertext.

Let's just hope it's not a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)...

Comment: it's not a one time pad, unless the pad really sucks or OP's source is astronomically unlucky.

Comment: @dandavis Yeah, I took a closer look at the ciphertext after I posted my answer. There are several repeats of ciphered words like "gsv", "zmw", "gl", etc showing that this is a pretty simple substitution cipher. Replacing the letters based on frequency alone will probably reveal 90% of the message.

Answer (score 0):

This type of cipher is a special substitution cipher known as [Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash), and is made by reversing the alphabet and replacing the last letter with the first, the penultimate letter with the second, and so on. It is called Atbash because it was originally done with the Hebrew alphabet, and it took its name from the first and last, and second and penultimate letters in that alphabet.

[Substitution ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) replace the letters of the message with other letters. [Caesar shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) and Atbash are fairly simple substitution ciphers to crack, because once you've made a few guesses it's easy to spot the system that has been used to decide on the substitutions.